# Minimum euclidean spanning tree in n dimensional space

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry

I need to compute the minimum euclidean spanning tree in $\mathbb R^d$ and do it with some algorithm that can do it with complexity near to $\Omega(n \log n)$ where $n$ is the size of the point set.

Right now I'm thinking about usage of delaunay triangulation for my set of points and after that use some MST algorithms like Prim\Kruskal, but as far as I see this won't give me needed complexity bounds.

Could someone point me to the right references about this problem from which I could:

1. Learn theory behind
2. Write exact algorithm to solve this problem

Comment: Is the $n$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and the one in $\Omega(n \log n)$ the same? I'd suppose they are not, and the latter is the size of the point set.

Comment: @lisyarus yes, you are right, n is the size of the point set, not amount of dimensions. Sorry, I will edit question.